# Cannot create more than 8 instances of JavaFx MediaPlayer

Tags: java, javafx, media-player

I have a very strange issue, only on my Mac.

I'm creating an application where 12 videos must be played at the same time. When I instantiate them, only the first 8 are working ok. The others shows a blank space. NO error or exception is thrown.

The same, identical code runs perfectly on Ubuntu.

I tried to increase stack memory, turn off hw acceleration, reduce video sizes, use of Platform.runLater to init videos: no luck.

Why this?

Comment: Does “No error or exception is thrown” include setting [MediaPlayer.onError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#onErrorProperty) to monitor for suppressed exceptions?

Comment: Yes. Tried also with different video files.